# Extended logical volume in LVM still shows old size

Tags: lvm

I have setup a server with LVM, and at first I juset created a small logical volume named 'root' of about 10GB, but later changed my mind. I extended it to 1TiB, but my server still is in two minds of how big the partition (or mountpoint, I'm not sure) actually is.

I used the #lvextend command in the console to extend the logical volume, not through webmin.

Here's a screengrab from webmin that maybe shows it more clearly.

[image: Screencapture of LVM module in webmin]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you're expecting more free space... `lvextend` resizes the logical volume, you also need to resize the filesystem:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/Hulkvg-root
```

(as `root`; I don't know how to do that through the Webmin interface).