# Mounted logical volume size not matching actual volume size

Tags: mount, lvm

I used `lvextend` to increase my logical volume from 1 physical drive to 3. This seemed to go fine:

```
$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/nbd1  dbvg lvm2 a--  139.70g    0
  /dev/nbd2  dbvg lvm2 a--  139.70g    0
  /dev/nbd3  dbvg lvm2 a--  139.70g    0
$ sudo vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  dbvg   3   1   0 wz--n- 419.09g    0
$ sudo lvs
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize 
  dblv dbvg -wi-ao---- 419.09g
```

Until I actually mounted the device and tried `df -h`:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/dbvg/dblv /mnt/virtual
$ df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/mapper/dbvg-dblv  138G  122G   15G  90% /mnt/virtual
```

It seems like the mount only uses one of the disks (or something is cached and hasn't been updated yet), but why? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Extended logical volume in LVM still shows old size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273066/extended-logical-volume-in-lvm-still-shows-old-size/273068#273068)

Comment: What's the history of these devices? Was there originally a file system (or file systems) on one of the `/dev/nbd{1,2,3}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you pass the `-r` (or `--resizefs`) option to `lvextend`? If not, you need to take an extra step.

By default `lvextend` will extend the LV, but will leave the file system contained within that LV untouched. The file system is what you mount and what `df` reports the size of.

You have to manually extend the file system to make it aware the underlying *device* has grown.

The way to extend it will vary depending on the actual file system; e.g. for ext2/ext3/ext4 the tool to use is `resize2fs`, for xfs the tool is `xfs_growfs`, etc.

Some file systems will allow *online* resizes while others will require you to unmount them beforehand.

Comment: Yep, I forgot to pass -r, so I just had to do `resize2fs`, so this was the solution! Thank you very much!